# Add custom params on nkzawa socket.iO-client for the handshake

Tags: java, socket.io

I want to be able to add custom params in the client for the handshake.

In the html client I am doing this

```
var socket = io('http://192.168.1.120:3000/socket', {query: user});
```

where user is an json object with data

I want to be able to do the same in java, I am using the library nkzawa socket.io-client

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@nkzawa replied me in the repository

https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java/issues/33

I just need to add the parameters to the URL

```
IO.socket("http://SERVER_URL:3000/socket?userid=100");
```